# Automate The Boring Stuff - Collatz Sequence

Tags: python, sequence, collatz

I'm new to Python and I having issues with my Collatz Sequence project in the Automate the Boring Stuff book. When I run my code it "prints" 2 of each number. I can't figure out why it is duplicating each number.  Anyone have any ideas?

Here are the directions to the short project:

Write a function named collatz() that has one parameter named number. If the number is even, then collatz() should print number // 2 and return this value. If the number is odd, then collatz() should print and return 3 * number + 1. Then write a program that lets the user type in an integer and that keeps calling collatz() on that number until the function returns the value 1.

```
def collatz(number):
if number % 2 == 0:
    print(number // 2)
    return number // 2
    
elif number % 2 == 1:
    print(3 * number + 1)
    return 3 * number + 1

print('Enter number: ')
try:
    x = int(input())
    while x != 1:
        collatz(x)
        x = collatz(x)        
except ValueError:
    print('Please use whole numbers only')
```

When I enter the number 3 I get this:

Enter number:
3
10
10
5
5
16
16
8
8
4
4
2
2
1
1

Comment: Welcome to the site. The code you have posted would give an indentation error. Please post a [mre].

Comment: You are calling `collatz` twice..

Comment: Axe319 - I'm first calling collatz(x) and then I want to use the Return value to go back through the While Loop. How do I get this new value to = x?

Comment: You can just totally remove the first function call, when you write `x = collatz(x)`, it will both print and return the new value.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is on the line:

```
    while x != 1:
        collatz(x)
        x = collatz(x)
```

You are calling `collatz` twice, so it is printing each number twice.

Comment: after the collatz(number) function runs, how do I get this new Return Value to equal = x?

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I removed the collatz(x) line and all seems good now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Here is the debugged version:

```
def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
        return number // 2
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        print(3 * number + 1)
        return 3 * number + 1

print('Enter number: ')
try:
    x = int(input())
    while x != 1:
        x = collatz(x)
except ValueError:
    print('Please use whole numbers only')
```